# Running MySQL from Windows 7 command line

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

I want to run a brief MySQL script from the Windows 7 command line.  The command line text I am using looks like:

```
C:\> C:\my path\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt --init-file=C:\\mysql-script.txt
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error message in the Windows 7 command line:

```
C:\my is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I have researched this online, but the solutions center around setting a new Windows environmental variable.  I do not think I should create an environmental variable called 'my'.  So what else can I do in order to run mysqld-nt from the Windows 7 command line?

It is important that MySQL not be running when I do this, so I need to call it from the Windows 7 command line and not use the MySQL command line client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space between "my" and "path".

Try:

```
"C:\my path\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt" --init-file=C:\\mysql-script.txt
```

You need the quotes to wrap any directory structure containing a space.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right in the error:

> C:\my is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file

What is `C:\my path`? Is that really your file system path?

If so, your command would be; note the quotes to keep "my path" together:

```
"C:\my path\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt" --init-file=C:\\mysql-script.txt
```

But more likely, `my path` should be the actual file system path on your Windows 7 install.

Comment: +1 Thank you.  I used the term "C:\my path" to represent that the first directory level has a two word name with a space in between the two words.  On a different topic, are you suggesting that I create an environmental variable called mysqld-nt and set its value to "C:\my path\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt"?  Would that make the correct syntax become mysqld-nt --init-file-C:\\MySQL-script.txt?

Comment: my path is very long.  It would be nice to be able to abbreviate "C:\my path\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt" to something like "mysqld_ref" on the command line.  Do you know of a way to do that?